# Contact listener not working for multiple members of a vector

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

In my game.cpp file, I have created a vector to store all of the "collectible" objects created in the game, at the moment there is only one object.

This is shown below:

```
std::vector<Collectible> m_coins;

m_coins = { *m_coin };
```

I have also created a loop to check if each member of the vector has been marked for deletion, as shown below:

```
    for (auto it = m_coins.begin(); it != m_coins.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->marked())
        {
            m_pWorld->DestroyBody(it->GetBody());
            m_coins.erase(it);

            score++;
            std::cout << "Score: " << score << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I have also created a contact listener, which should call the onCollect function of the collectible if contacted by the character.

What I have so far is shown below, this throws up an error, saying "identifier m_coins is undefined".

```
    b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();

    int typeA = (int)fixtureA->GetUserData();
    int typeB = (int)fixtureB->GetUserData();

    if (typeA == PhysicalThing::CHARACTER)
    {
        Character * m_character = (Character *)fixtureA->GetBody()->GetUserData();

        if (typeB == PhysicalThing::COLLECTIBLE)
        {
            for (auto it = m_coins.begin(); it != m_coins.end(); it++)
            {
                Collectible* it = (Collectible *)fixtureB->GetBody()->GetUserData();
                it->onCollect(fixtureA);
            }
        }

    }
```

Also, here is my contact listener header file:

```
#pragma once

/*!
\file blockCircleContactListener.h
*/

#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>
#include "game.h"
#include "dynamicCircle.h"
#include "dynamicBlock.h"
#include "staticBlock.h"
#include "kinematicBlock.h"
#include "winnerPole.h"
#include "character.h"
#include "simpleEnemy.h"
#include "collectible.h"

/*! \class CharacterContactListener
\brief A listener which listens for contacts between blocks
*/
class CharacterContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
public:
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact); //!< Called when two fixtures begin to touch
    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact); //!< Called when two fixtures cease to touch
};
```

My question, in short, is how can I correctly reference my vector and all of its data, and how do I create a contact listener that will check each member of the vector for contact and then execute the function for that specific object as expected?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that in your first snippet, the correct way to erase an element using an iterator is `it = m_coins.erase(it);`

Comment: in c++ 17 you can check for  types like this - if constexpr (std::is_same< typeB == PhysicalThing::COLLECTIBLE >)

Comment: I assume this is in place of if(typeB == PhysicalThing::COLLECTIBLE) ? Also Im having an error with the is_same element. Expects a declaration.

Comment: fix - if constexpr (std::is_same< typeB,PhysicalThing::COLLECTIBLE >) Defined in header <type_traits> can look at doc https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: TypeB and PhysicalThing::Collectible are not type names